# Java Script accordion functionality problem

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

Im making a app in django which needs a accordion. This is the following HTML code

```
{% load static %}
{% for comp in comps %}


<script src="{% static 'main/app.js' %}"></script>

<div class="accordion-body">
    <div class="accordion">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="label">
        {{comp.name}}
        {{comp.country}}, {{comp.city}}
        </div>

        <div class="content">{{comp.descr}}</div>
        <hr>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the css which actually hides the content. Note Ive taken out a lot of uneccessary css like font-size and colors.

```
.accordion .label::before {
    content: '+';
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  
  
  .accordion .content {
    text-align: justify;
    width: 780px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  .accordion .container.active .content {
    height: 150px;
  }
```

Finally this is javascript which is meant to add a Event Listener

```
const accordions = document.getElementsByClassName('container');

Array.from(accordions).forEach((accordion)=>{
   accordion.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active')
  })
})
```

The `active` class isnt being added.

There might be a problem with linking the js with the HTML doc since when I run the app this is what I get in the command line.
`GET /static/main/app.js HTTP/1.1` 
The location is definitely correct

Comment: `GET /static/main/app.js` and what's the response status?

Comment: response status is 304

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements.

```
let containers = document.getElementsByClassName('container');

for(let i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
  containers[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active')
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several points to be noticed in your source code setup, each to be handled.

- Your `<script>...` tag is inside the django `{% for ... %}` loop, means the same script is being loaded multiple times (depending upon size of your `comp`). Move your `<script>...` out of the loop. This will also prevent multiple declaration errors, like `accordions has already been declared`.
- Your `<script>...` tag is loaded before the `container` class div, and the script is not waiting for document to load, so your `document.getElementsByClassName('container')` won't be getting anything anyway. Try adding this function call inside a document load event listener in your script, or position your script load at the bottom of your html code (preferably after the `container` class div).
- The `accordion` variable is a list, and not a single `HTMLElement` object. Therefore, the `addEventListener('click'...` won't work. Try this

```js
...
const accordions = document.getElementsByClassName('container');

Array.from(accordions).forEach((accordion)=>{
   accordion.addEventListener('click'...//rest of your code
   ...
})
...
```

- You have not included the stylesheet in html (if you have taken that part out here only then its alright).

There could be other problems as well apart from the ones I noticed from you currently provided code. But these points should help you too.

Comment: It still doesnt work. I even put the code in the html so the problem isnt the script tag. When I inspect in chrome I'm getting an error:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'accordions' has already been declared. Even in the event listener section when I inspect

Comment: Even in the event Listener section when I inspect there isnt anything

Comment: If accordions has already been declared is an error, then have you followed my first point?

Comment: Yes the java script tag is after the for loo[

Comment: Java script tag is outside of the for loop

Comment: I changed the javascript to what I have now maybe the problem is there